# nested foreach combine php

Tags: php, foreach, nested

I keep geting wrong output as always get last amount for each wallet, anyone can help? thanks a lot.

```
foreach ( $xml->NewDataSet->WalletData as $PGW) {
    printf("%s\t%s\n", $PGW->walletID, $PGW->Walletamount);
}
```

this foreach output is:

```
walletID    Walletamount
1           100
4           40
```

second foreach as blow:

```
foreach ( $xml2->NewDataSet->Provider as $provide) {
    if ($provide->WalletType == 'Black Wallet') {
        printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", " ", $provide->WalletID, $provide->WalletName));
    }   
}
```

output is:

```
amount   WalletID  WalletName  
         1         A
         2         B
         3         C
         4         D
         5         E
         6         F
```

how do i combine two foreach and output like this.

```
amount   walletname
100.0    A
  0.0    B
  0.0    C
 40.0    D
  0.0    E
  0.0    F
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would build an array:

```
$wallets = array();

foreach ( $xml2->NewDataSet->Provider as $provide) {
    if ($provide->WalletType == 'Black Wallet') {
        $wallets[$provide->WalletID] = array('name' => $provide->WalletName, 'amount' => 0);
    }   
}

foreach ( $xml->NewDataSet->WalletData as $PGW) {
    $wallets[$PGW->walletID]['amount'] = $PGW->Walletamount;
}

for( $i=0;$i<count($wallets);$i++ ){
    printf("%s\t%s\n", $wallets[$i]['amount'], $wallets[$i]['name']);
}
```

Comment: it works. except a error as  "llegal offset type in $wallets[$provide->WalletID] ", but i fix it...thanks a lot...

Comment: Might have to cast it to an INT. What did you do to fix it?

Comment: I fixed it with strval() like this "$wallets[strval($provide->WalletID)] " .

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is:

```
foreach ( $xml2->NewDataSet->Provider as $provide) {
    if ($provide->WalletType == 'Black Wallet') {
        if (isset($xml->NewDataSet->WalletData[$provide->WalletID])) {
            printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", $xml->NewDataSet->WalletData[$provide->WalletID]->Walletamount, $provide->WalletID, $provide->WalletName));
        } else {
            printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n", 0, $provide->WalletID, $provide->WalletName));
        }
    }   
}
```

But I have no idea what your variables `$xml` and `$xml2` are.

Comment: $result = $soapClient -> GetWallet($params);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result->dsResult->any);  $result2 = $soapClient -> GetProvider($params);
$xml2 = new SimpleXMLElement($result2->dsResult->any);

Answer (score 0):

I haven't started it, because you haven't provide the arays in normal form but it has to work

```
<?php
$array1=Array ();
foreach ( $xml->NewDataSet->WalletData as $PGW) {
    $array1[$PGW->walletID]=$PGW->Walletamount;
}
foreach ( $xml2->NewDataSet->Provider as $provide) {
    if ($provide->WalletType == 'Black Wallet') {
        if(isset($array1[$provide->WalletID]))
            $data=$array1[$provide->WalletID];
        else
            $data=0;
        echo sprintf("%s\t%.1F\n", " ", $data, $provide->WalletName);
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: It works,  except a error as "llegal offset type in $wallets[$PGW->WalletID] ", but i fix it...thanks a lot